# Winforms - Webbrowser add onClick event to table cell

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I've created a html string containing a table for my winforms application. i added a webbrowser control to show various information about the current status of the program.
I now want the tables `<th>` tags to execute a function filling another control of the form based on the content of the cell.

For Testing purpose i added this function to the forms code

```
private void testClick(object sender)
{
        MessageBox.Show("Hello there");
}
```

combined with the html content

```
<th onclick=\"testClick(this);\">" + myVariable + "</th>
```

resulting in this:
[image]

My question now is how do i get the generated html table to work with the c# code behind the form? I'm specifically interested in the value of `myVariable`

Additional info: the html code gets genereated by a model class like a ToString method

Answer (score 1):

to avoid getting this error, set the `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` property of the WebBrowser to true.

And please note that testClick is an event in your c# code and not in the document loaded in the WebBrowser.

To capture click event of the WebBrowser element in your code, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933979/how-to-capture-click-event-for-any-button-inside-in-web-browser-control)

Comment: just supressing the error message seems like not a good thing to do and i wrote in question that the testClick method is part of the forms code and not part of the loaded html string. anyway thanks for the link, not the way i wanted to do it but i guess it will do.