# Click a button in website, with use c# webbrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, html

i want to click this 'Yağmalama yap'(Green Button, picture link in the end of my writing) button with use my c# application. When i click second button(Choose), i can select this checkbox with this codes:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("slot214750").InvokeMember("Click"); 
}
```

http://postimg.org/image/c5awzc9wt/

But it isn't enough. I Need to my third button work. That's what i want; I will click my third button(Attack), then my application click this green button.(Button name is 'Yağmalama yap').
I Hope this picture will help you to help me.

http://postimg.org/image/ofkz4w47p/

I'm waiting your helps, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want to catch the 'attack' button click event in C#, and in response click your other button. [Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7130533/871910) you attach a web page event to your C# code.